# Is there a WiFi "bridge" router (or device) that can make a permanent hotspot from a University wireless requires a username and password?

Tags: wifi, networking, network-adapter

There have been [similar questions](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/6urn10/how_to_connect_google_home_to_university_wifi/) that *seem* to offer a [WiFi "bridge" solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HZWOQZ6) but I have tried several of these bridge routers and none of them work to "bride" a University WiFi that requires a Username and Password to log in. The TP link "bridge" router claimed to do just that, but after an hour on the phone working through it we find that they can not connect through a "portal" either.

Is there anyway at all of make an always on WiFi "bridge" or "hot spot"?

I have tried Windows 10 "Hotspot" but it times out, and for some reason Android hotspot just does not seem to work at all on this network.

Thanks all!

```
SSID:   [MyUniversity]wireless
Protocol:   802.11ac
Security type:  WPA2-Enterprise
Type of sign-in info:   Microsoft: Protected EAP (PEAP)
Network band:   5 GHz
Network channel:    161
IPv4 address:   172.28.88.100
IPv4 DNS servers:   128.146.1.7
128.146.48.7
Primary DNS suffix: [MyUniversity]wireless.[something]-state.edu
Manufacturer:   Intel Corporation
Description:    Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
Driver version: 19.50.1.6
Physical address (MAC): C2-32-73-69-0F-35
```

Comment: You're going to have to deal with your campus network admin.

Comment: 6 7/8 thank you for the comment but why do you say that? What is it about the University network that does not allow a bridge connection?

Comment: Because most orgainzations are not too happy when someone adds equipment to their network that they have 0 control over without permission and that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all routers where you can install open source firmware (OpenWRT, Tomato, ...) will be able to do this. However, you'll need some familiarity with Linux to set this up (or you need to know someone who does). University networks use EAP (as shown), and `wpa_supplicant` which is the standard WPA authorization client supports this, given the correct configuration file (where you'd also enter username and password).

Now enable NAT (which should be the default), and you have your hotspot.